# How to address hashed remoteEntry.xxxxxx.js in routing using loadRemoteModule in module federation

Tags: angular, webpack, caching, hash, angular-module-federation

I want to use **hashed remoteEntry** in order to overcome **cached remoteEntry.js** issue in micro front ends apps. currentry I have used

```
filename: 'remoteEntry.[hash:16].js',
```

in my mfe webpack.config.js but dont know how to address it in my main app routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainRouteContainerComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
          loadRemoteModule({
            remoteEntry: `${environment.Url}/remoteEntry.??????.js`,
            type: 'module',
            exposedModule: './Module',
          }).then((m) => m.RemoteEntryModule),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I also added this

```
new ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin(),
```

into plugins section of mfe webpack.config.js

the way of using

```
ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin
```

doesnt make any sense and obviously at build, main app is still looking for remoteEntry.js file instead of remoteEntry.xxxxxx.js. where I went wrong? and maybe better and more stragitforward solutions for cache issue (except no-cache)?